# Error: "'PhoneAuthOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Builder'" in Unity C#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am developing a mobile application in Unity using C#, and I'm trying to implement phone authentication using Firebase. However, I encountered an error stating that "'PhoneAuthOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Builder'"

Here are the steps I followed and the code snippet where the error occurs:

I have imported the necessary Firebase packages and added them to my project.
I've created a script that handles the authentication process.
In the script, I'm using the Firebase SDK for Unity and attempting to create a PhoneAuthOptions object using the PhoneAuthOptions.Builder.
Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
private void VerifyPhoneNumber()
    {
        phoneAuthProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(firebaseAuth);

        PhoneAuthOptions options = new PhoneAuthOptions.Builder(FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance)
        .SetPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
        .SetActivity(this)
        .SetCallbacks(this)
        .Build();

        phoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(options,
          verificationCompleted: (credential) =>
          {
              Debug.Log("Verification complete: " + credential);
              // Auto-sms-retrieval or instant validation has succeeded (Android only).
              // There is no need to input the verification code.
              // `credential` can be used instead of calling GetCredential().
          },
          verificationFailed: (error) =>
          {
              Debug.Log("The verification code was not sent: " + error);
              // The verification code was not sent.
              // `error` contains a human readable explanation of the problem.
          },
          codeSent: (id, token) =>
          {
              verificationId = id;
              verificationMessagePanel.SetActive(true);
              phoneNumberVerificationPanel.SetActive(false);
              Debug.Log("Verification code was successfully sent via SMS: " + id);
              // Verification code was successfully sent via SMS.
              // `id` contains the verification id that will need to passed in with
              // the code from the user when calling GetCredential().
              // `token` can be used if the user requests the code be sent again, to
              // tie the two requests together.
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) =>
          {
              Debug.Log("`id` contains the verification id of the request that timed out: " + id);
              // Called when the auto-sms-retrieval has timed out, based on the given
              // timeout parameter.
              // `id` contains the verification id of the request that timed out.
          });
    }
```

I have verified that I have the latest version of the Firebase SDK (11.0.0) and that all the necessary dependencies are installed.

Am I missing any steps or packages? How can I resolve this error and successfully use PhoneAuthOptions.Builder in Unity with C#?

Thank you for your help!

I tried using the "VerifyPhoneNumber" method without the PhoneAuthOptions but I get a warning which is "Warning CS0618 'PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(string, uint, ForceResendingToken, PhoneAuthProvider.VerificationCompleted_DEPRECATED, PhoneAuthProvider.VerificationFailed, PhoneAuthProvider.CodeSent, PhoneAuthProvider.CodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut)' is obsolete: 'Please use `VerifyPhoneNumber(PhoneAuthOptions, VerificationCompleted, VerificationFailed, CodeSent, CodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut)` instead'"

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: I am also receivng same error. Sms is not sent .. Did you find any solutions.

Comment: Here is an example of authorization by phone number https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/blob/3061aef6cee7c2fcc4e8619fd9242f875ba17af1/auth/testapp/Assets/Firebase/Sample/Auth/UIHandler.cs#L838
Just use the default constructor with initialization of the class properties you need

Answer (score 1):

If verificationFailed callback isn't ran, we don't even reach to the firebase side. And the warning about obsolete method looks partially unwanted.

Try apply example from testapp project from firebase's github repo for Unity:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/blob/v11.0.0/auth/testapp/Assets/Firebase/Sample/Auth/UIHandler.cs#L839C20-L839C37

```
 var phoneAuthProvider = Firebase.Auth.PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
  phoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(
    new Firebase.Auth.PhoneAuthOptions {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
        TimeoutInMilliseconds = phoneAuthTimeoutMs,
        ForceResendingToken = null
    },
    verificationCompleted: (cred) => {
      DebugLog("Phone Auth, auto-verification completed");
      if (signInAndFetchProfile) {
        auth.SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWithOnMainThread(
          HandleSignInWithAuthResult);
      } else {
        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWithOnMainThread(HandleSignInWithUser);
      }
    },
    verificationFailed: (error) => {
      DebugLog("Phone Auth, verification failed: " + error);
    },
    codeSent: (id, token) => {
      phoneAuthVerificationId = id;
      DebugLog("Phone Auth, code sent");
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) => {
      DebugLog("Phone Auth, auto-verification timed out");
    });
```

Note the usage for this class exactly for v11.0.0

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Declare `verificationId` and Initialise `mAuth` object first:

```
String verificationId;
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

**2.** Write code for Firebase Phone Authentication:

```
PhoneAuthOptions options =
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .setActivity(this)
                    .setCallbacks(new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                            // Code for verification failed !!!
                        }

                        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                        @Override
                        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                            verificationId = s; // Store OTP credentials string in verificationId.
                            verifyOtp();
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

**3.** Create a separate function for `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential` to auto login in case your device identifies the incoming otp message.

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Code for VERIFICATION COMPLETE
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration failed !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
}
```

**4.** Compare `verificationId` string with 6 digit `otpText` string entered by user using `verifyOtp()`, in case your device failed to verify incoming otp message. But make sure that you have already created two objects. One for `EditText` to enter 6 digit Otp and another for `Button` to submit that Otp.

> EditText `otpText`

> Button `submitButton`

```
private void verifyOtp() {
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, otpText.getText().toString());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Code for VERIFICATION COMPLETE
            } else if (otpText.getText().length() < 6) {
                otpText.setError("OTP can't be less than 6 digits");
                otpText.requestFocus();
            } else {
                otpText.setError("Invalid OTP");
                otpText.setText("");
                otpText.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    });
}
```